# civilizations 5 not starting

Tags: 18.04, games

I'm trying to start civ5 on my laptop, Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS,64bit, 4gb ram, Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 520 @ 2.40GHz × 4, Intel® HD Graphics (ILK), gnome 3.28.2.
File is executable, trying to start game from terminal. It's not starting, not showing any errors, if I'm doing ./Civ5XP
I tried with `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libopenal.so.1 ./Civ5XP`, I was getting error

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib32/libopenal.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

After putting libopenal.so.1 in /usr/lib32, error is gone and game is not starting and I'm not getting any error. 
Here is ldd output

```
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f84000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => ./libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xf7dd4000)
    libMiles.so => ./libMiles.so (0xf7d4c000)
    libtbb.so.2 => ./libtbb.so.2 (0xf7d28000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => ./libssl.so.1.0.0 (0xf7cd2000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf7b64000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7b45000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7b3b000)
    libc++.so.1 => ./libc++.so.1 (0xf7a91000)
    libcxxrt.so => ./libcxxrt.so (0xf7a72000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7896000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f85000)
    libsteam_api.so => ./libsteam_api.so (0xf787d000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0xf7811000)
    libopenal.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1 (0xf7766000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7761000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf765f000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7641000)
    libuuid.so.1 => ./libuuid.so.1 (0xf763b000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf761c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7496000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf746a000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0xf73ed000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0xf73b2000)
    libsndio.so.6.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsndio.so.6.1 (0xf73a0000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf739c000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf7395000)
    libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0xf7272000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0xf7257000)
```

Am I missing something? :D